# Log scale in 3dplot using matploblib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to create a 3D plot with the z axis in log scale. This is an example code.

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def fun(x, y):
    return x**2 + y

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
x = y = np.arange(-3.0, 3.0, 0.05)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
zs = np.array([fun(x,y) for x,y in zip(np.ravel(X), np.ravel(Y))])
Z = zs.reshape(X.shape)

ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)

ax.set_xlabel('X Label')
ax.set_ylabel('Y Label')
ax.set_zlabel('Z Label')

plt.show()
```

I tried ax.set_zscale('log') and ax.zaxis.set_scale('log') but that is not working. It should be possible though. If I use ax.plot_surface(X, Y, np.log(Z)) the z ticks are off. I could not find an answer to this seemingly simple problem. I hope you can help.

Comment: A simple work-around would be `ax.plot_surface(X, Y, np.log10(Z))`, which will plot the log of Z. Then you could indicate it in the axis like `ax.set_zlabel('Log(Z)')`

Comment: That is not really a solution but a fallback plan.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that Matplotlib actually cannot properly do logscale in 3D plots. It's a known bug ([#209](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/209)) from 2011 that as of Nov 2023 still had no solution.